# string: replace "(" with "\("

Tags: java, regex, string, bash, escaping

i have to send a string to the bash, which contains an escape sequence. For example, i have to replace special characters like "(" with "(", because the bash else throws errors. I trtied like

```
public class escape {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("\\");
        String s = "(foo)";
        System.out.println(s);
        s = s.replaceAll("(", "\\(");
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

with no luck. Please help!!

thanks

Comment: Note, you are still going to be open to injection attacks, if that is important or ever becomes important.

Answer (score 6):

[`String.replaceAll`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) uses a regular expression, which isn't what you want here. Just use [`String.replace`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29):

```
s = s.replace("(", "\\(");
```

Comment: Funniest thing is that to implement simple string replace, it *does use* regexp. Pattern.compile(target.toString(), Pattern.LITERAL).matcher(this).replaceAll(Matcher.quoteReplacement(replacement.toString()));

Comment: >>Simpler and faster. +1; not really 'faster'

Comment: @bestsss: tomorrow it may be faster. Today it definitely is simpler and safer.

Comment: @cherouvim: I seriously doubt String will drop the use of regExp to impl. replace, unless it ever happens, it won't be faster. Plus, you need to run your code now, not tomorrow. I do realize the need to use the standard APIs available, yet, I'd disagree they are always 'safer'. Again, the code I posted is dating far prior RegExp (1.4), and CharSequence (1.5), around 1999 or so.

Comment: @bestsss: I would say that unless you *want* to use a regular expression, using an API which doesn't work in terms of regular expressions is safer, in that it's easier not to mess up.

Comment: @Jon: sure, I, myself, virtually can't use regular expressions, can't think of in such terms (regex). B/c String.replace uses internally regular expressions 'I know' it's not fast [and it bugs me]. That's my point, so no regular expression syntax is always good to me, but decision to implement String.replace() via regexp is, well, 'not good'.

Comment: @bestsss: I meant simpler and safer than my solution with replaceAll.

Answer (score 1):

```
s = s.replaceAll("\\(", "\\\\(");
```

Comment: Unless the OP really *wants* to use regular expressions, why make it complicated?

Comment: I think the second argument should still be `"\\\("` - it isn't a regex.

Comment: No, the second argument is correct - parentheses still need to be escaped in the replacement.  Also, I really wish comments allowed code formatting, so I could just explain the issue as an addendum to this answer.

Comment: OK. Got it. You need to escape the slash, although it doesn't seem to have a real function (aside from escaping `$`).

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Yes, replace() is definitelly better in this case.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the ( is a special character according to the regexp syntax (which is used by replaceAll).

You should take Skeet's advice and use "replace" instead in this case, but to give you an idea of how the regexp version works, here's a fixed example:

```
public class test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("\\");
        String s = "(foo)";
        System.out.println(s);
        s = s.replaceAll("\\(", "\\\\(");
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at all regexp solutions (String.replace(CharSequence, CharSequence) is also regexp impl. under the hoold), here a piece of code residing for ages in one of the Util classes. [This is why it still uses StringBuffer (old times)]

```
public static String replace(String strToRepl,String orig,String repl){
    if (strToRepl==null) return null;
    int len=strToRepl.length();
    StringBuffer buf=null;

    int ind;
    int origLen=orig.length();
    int start=0;

    while (start<len&&(ind=strToRepl.indexOf(orig,start))>=0){
        if (buf==null) buf=new StringBuffer(len*3/2);
        buf.append(strToRepl.substring(start,ind)).append(repl);
        start=origLen+ind;
    }

    if (buf!=null){
        if (start<len)
            buf.append(strToRepl.substring(start));
        return buf.toString();
    }

    return strToRepl;
}
```

Comment: How is this better than using .replace? Is it faster and if yes how much faster and under what circumstances?

Comment: That always should be faster than regexp. For instance the method above will be hell a lot faster (and make no allocations either) if there are no replaces [the op idea supports rare to no replaces]. The code is easier (much much) easier to inline by the JVM as well. If you really need field alike micro-benchmark I guess I can perform 'em. Yet, the RegExp will need to do just like that but also compile the RegExp (both), create few other instances (allocations) in the process and generate the same amounts of substrings in the end. It depends on the length the string to replace...

Comment: ...I'd just guess and say 4-5times.